# How to set Dynamic types based off variables in Typescript

Tags: typescript

If I have a type such as:

`type Colors = "blue" | "red" | "green"`

which means that if a variable is of that type, it can only be one of those three strings, not just any string... But how would I go about setting that type, based off an array that I define? Such as...

```
const DEFAULT_COLORS = ["orange", "yellow", "purple"];

type Colors = typeof DEFAULT_COLORS[number];
```

however, this just says "variable of type Color can be typeof any position in  the array... which are all strings, thus it can be a string."

I want it to dynamically set the type based on the variable to be constants

Comment: Use an enum, that's what they're for. Typescript has had them for an awfully long time...they even have their own chapter in the TS handbook. POST EDIT: enums are strongly-typed, you don't have to specify the compiler already knows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using TS 3.4+, you can use a `const` assertion to prevent type widening.

```
/* This type alias converts Array<U> => U */
type ArrayType<T extends any[]> = T extends Array<infer U> ? U : never;

const colors = ["red", "blue", "green"] as const;
// typeof colors = ("red"|"blue"|"green")[]

type Color = ArrayType<typeof colors> // "red" | "blue" | "green"
```

If you're using an older version of typescript, you could use something like this:

```
/* This function prevents type widening to "string" */
function typedArray<T extends string>(...args: T[]): T[] {
  return args;
}

const colors = typedArray("red","blue","green");
// typeof colors = ("red"|"blue"|"green")[]
```

I agree with Jared Smith's comment though, an enum would probably be the simplest solution

```
enum Color {
  RED,
  BLUE,
  GREEN
}

function doSomethingColorful(c: Color) {...}
// invoked like
doSomethingColorful(color.RED);
```